# How to use recursion to find and print multiple shortest paths from point A to point B? (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion

First post on here so forgive me if I do some things wrong. I cannot figure out how to recursively find and print all the shortest paths from point A to point B.

I am making a program that has a robot go from point A to point B using the shortest path possible. The program has to use recursion and find and print all the shortest paths that the robot can take from point A to get to point B. For example, if the robot starts at point (1, 2) and needs to make its way to point (3, 5), then the program should print 10 paths with only 5 moves (NNNEE for example). Here are the two most important functions, sorry that the code is so messy.

```
void Robot::FindPath(const Board &board)
{
    string path = "";
    vector < string > pathsVector;
    MoveRobot(startingX,
              startingY,
              treasureX,
              treasureY,
              path,
              "",
              0,
              pathsVector);
}

void Robot::MoveRobot(const int &startingX,
                      const int &startingY,
                      const int &treasureX,
                      const int &treasureY,
                      const string &path,
                      const string &lastMove,
                      const int &numMovesDirection,
                      vector<string> &pathVector)
{
    if (startingX == treasureX && startingY == treasureY)
    {
        cout << path << endl;
        PathCount++;
        pathVector.push_back(path);
        return;
    }
    else if (startingY == treasureY)
    {
        if (startingX - treasureX > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "W" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "W" && 
                      (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                       numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX - 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "W",
                          "W",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "W")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX - 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "W",
                          "W",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
        else if (startingX - treasureX < 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "E" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "E" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX + 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "E",
                          "E",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "E")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX + 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "E",
                          "E",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (startingX == treasureX)
    {
        if (startingY - treasureY > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "S" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "S" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY - 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "S",
                          "S",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "S")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY - 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "S",
                          "S",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
        else if (startingY + treasureY > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "N" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "N" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY + 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "N",
                          "N",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "N")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY + 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "N",
                          "N",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (startingX - treasureX > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "W" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "W" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX - 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "W",
                          "W",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "W")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX - 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "W",
                          "W",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
        else if (startingX - treasureX < 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "E" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "E" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX + 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "E",
                          "E",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "E")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX + 1,
                          startingY,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "E",
                          "E",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
        else if (startingY - treasureY > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "S" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "S" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY - 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "S",
                          "S",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "S")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY - 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "S",
                          "S",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
        else if (startingY + treasureY > 0)
        {
            if (lastMove == "N" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)
            {

            }
            else if (lastMove == "N" && 
                     (numMovesDirection < MaxStepsDir || 
                      numMovesDirection > MaxStepsDir))
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY + 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "N",
                          "N",
                          numMovesDirection + 1,
                          pathVector);
            }
            else if (lastMove != "N")
            {
                MoveRobot(startingX,
                          startingY + 1,
                          treasureX,
                          treasureY,
                          path + "N",
                          "N",
                          1,
                          pathVector);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the "return" in the first if statement is stopping the recursion, but I don't know where else I would end the recursion when all 10 shortest paths in the example I gave are found and printed. As it is it only prints EENNN. Please ignore the if statements that say "if (lastMove == "W" && numMovesDirection == MaxStepsDir)", I plan on filling those in later to get a different part of the program to work. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *First post on here so forgive me if I do some things wrong.* See what I can do, but no guarantees. Rather than taking that risk, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and give [ask] a read. At first glance, you may catch some flack for not having a [mcve]. Now I'm going to read the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I was about to apply `clang-format` (with my config) when I just saw your edit. That's a good one anyways.

Comment: Number of paths is exponential in size of input. Are you sure you really want them?

Comment: @n.m. Sorry if I'm interpreting your comment wrong but I only want the shortest possible paths and not all the paths in general. In the case of the example I gave the only paths I would want are the ones that would only be 5 moves long.

Comment: It applies to shortest paths too as all paths can well be of same length (not in all cases obviously but it's easy to build an example)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://pastebin.com/XMXkKm8W). There are about 2^32 paths, all of the same length. Each additional section with an X doubles the number,

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Sorry if I wasted anybody's time with this. There was both a basic misunderstanding of recursion on my part as well as a small error in the code. I didn't realize that recursion would automatically print all the shortest paths by backtracking and going down other paths. The mistake in my code that was preventing this was that in the large "else" near the end of my code, I accidentally put "else if (startingY - treasureY > 0)". This should just say "if (startingY - treasureY > 0)" since the whole point of that large else code block is to change both the x coordinate and y coordinate if neither of them are in the right position, and putting else if there prevents that. Once that else if is changed to if, it prints out all ten shortest paths for the example I gave.